# Populating and Sorting Three Columns of a DataGridView from Data in a Single MySQL Row Including Images

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

As the title says I'm trying to sort a DataGridView into 3 Columns using data from MYSQL. So far I managed to populate 2 of the 3 columns with the correct data using:

```
 'Load Shift Report Data
    Dim Com2 As MySqlCommand
    Connection.Open()
    Dim Shift_Status As String = "OPEN"
    Com2 = New MySqlCommand("SELECT Item0, Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5, Item6, Item7, Item8, Item9, Item10,
                            Item11, Item12, Item13, Item14, Item15, Item16, Item17
                            FROM tbl4ShiftReport WHERE USER_ID= '" + User_ID + "' AND Shift_Status= '" + Shift_Status + "';", Connection)
    Com2.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim MSDA2 As New MySqlDataAdapter(Com2)
    Dim DT2 As New DataTable()
    MSDA2.Fill(DT2)
    Connection.Close()

    If DT2.Rows.Count >= 1 Then
        Dim DT3 As New DataTable()
        For i As Integer = 0 To DT2.Rows.Count + 1
            DT3.Columns.Add()
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To DT2.Columns.Count - 1
            DT3.Columns("Column2").DataType = GetType(Decimal)
            DT3.Columns("Column3").DataType = GetType(Byte())
            DT3.Rows.Add()
            DT3.Rows(i)(0) = DT2.Columns(i).ColumnName
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To DT2.Columns.Count - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To DT2.Rows.Count - 1
                DT3.Rows(i)(j + 1) = DT2.Rows(j)(i)
            Next
        Next

        DataGridView2.DataSource = DT3
```

This is only working because I'm only getting one set of the Data and their Column names in the db and sorting them into the Data Table and then making this the data source for the datagrid.

But the third set of data for the third column in the datagrid, which I'm not getting yet in this example, are ftp links stored as strings to display in this third column as thumbnails. These links are in a separate table in mysql and I can reference them to the corresponding data however I'm unsure on how to accommodate this into the winforms table.

With this said my first question would be how can I sort this third column into the data table? Right now I'm basically putting the column names in column 1 and the data in column 2 but this third set of data I dont know how to sort it. I'm thinking making an if statement that if the column name starts with "item" put it in column 2 and if it starts with "img" put it in column 3 but still i need to sort that item1 goes with img1 and so on.

My second question would be once I sort the data how can I download the images and display them in that third column.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note that this is highly suggestive of poor schema design

Comment: I should put the images in a separate table in the db right? I should add that each item has its pertaining img so item1 goes with img1 and so on.

Comment: Yes. Correct ...

Comment: Ok! Thanks I'm editing the question to reflect this. I'm still uncertain of what to do to get it all into one table and display the images though.

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about all the non-sql stuff for the time being, and instead focus on the query. With that in mind, see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)